# Thread of Dispatchers.IO coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine, coroutinescope

I'm learning coroutines in Android. I have the following code:

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)

operator fun invoke(token: String, callback: TaskCallback) {
    scope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { userDataSource.saveApiToken(token) }
        callback.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

I expected that `userDataSource.saveApiToken(token)` will be called from separate thread, but it runs on the main thread (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper() returns true inside the method). 
What can be the cause? [my mistake]

I'm using Kotlin plugin version: 1.3.11-release-Studio3.2-1 and the following dependencies: kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1 and kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1

Comment: What `Thread.currentThread()` is returning?

Comment: It returns Thread[main,5,main]

Comment: Could you please check what thread here `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {  Thread.currentThread()  }`

Comment: I've just tested it and there is a different thread: `Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]`

Comment: Ok, my mistake, it returns Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-2,5,main]. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the point of using coroutines when your custom API again has a `TaskCallback`. Coroutines are there to remove callbacks. The code you have now could be rewritten without them in almost the same form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thread in the `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` block should be **background thread**. If we put logs there:

```
operator fun invoke(token: String, callback: TaskCallback) {
    scope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { Log.e("Log", "t: ${Thread.currentThread()}") }
        callback.onCompleted()
    }
}
```

we will see **Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1,5,main]**. So the thread is a **background thread**.
As @Marko Topolnik mentioned  in the comments, the main purpose of coroutines is to get rid of callbacks. Please try to refactor your code and remove `callback: TaskCallback`.